# Unable to connect with RPC connection - Simplecoin , Pushpool

Tags: php, bitcoin

I need to use Simplecoin pushpool frontend, to connect with bitcoins. I have install bitcoins, pushpool server. They are installed successfully. But while using the simplecoin (opensource [click here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=13164.0)) as frontend for pushpool server, i got this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught BitcoinClientException: [0]: Connect error: Connection refused (111) thrown in on line 0
```

I dont know what causes this error. I have changed the rpc connection details in includes/requiredFunctions.php as

```
$rpcType = "http"; // http or https
$rpcUsername = "rpcuser"; // username
$rpcPassword = "rpcpass"; // password
$rpcHost = "127.0.0.1";
$rpcPort = 8332;
```

and changed the mysql configs. can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you allowed the access of other IP's? Thats if your site is on another machine.

rpcallowip=* or rpcallowip=192.168. * .*